# Pyinstaller compiled Harfang 3d game not working

Tags: python

When I run it, I get:

```
(0:051:583:200) Harfang core 1.2.0 (build 1538b3acd3c9351b7b9108742a5f352c98b78e5d Feb 7 2019 09:51:22)
(0:056:555:200) See http://harfang3d.com/license for licensing terms
(0:204:585:600) Load plugins from 4 default paths
(0:206:580:300) Scanning for plugin in 'c:/Users/User/'...
(0:211:050:000) error: LoadSharedLibrary('sfextra.dll') failed, reason: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

(0:215:589:600) 0 plugin(s) loaded
(0:217:320:100) Scanning for plugin in 'c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI184562/base_library.zip/harfang/'...
(0:222:930:200) 0 plugin(s) loaded
(0:224:276:900) Scanning for plugin in 'c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI184562/lib-dynload/harfang/'...
(0:229:429:900) 0 plugin(s) loaded
(0:231:235:200) Scanning for plugin in 'c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI184562/harfang/'...
(0:236:044:700) 0 plugin(s) loaded
(0:238:165:200) 0 plugin(s) loaded
(0:240:725:100) Mount root driver 000002236AEAE4B0 (relative to '')
(0:256:356:600) warn: No renderer available, was LoadPlugins called successfully?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "flight_sim.py", line 4232, in
File "flight_sim.py", line 2575, in request_screen_mode
RuntimeError: RenderInit failed, was LoadPlugins called succesfully?
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @liggiorgio I'm trying to compile my Python Harfang 3D to an exe using pyinstaller but it doesn't work. I need it to run without errors.

Comment: `error: LoadSharedLibrary('sfextra.dll') failed, reason: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` sounds like the dll is not where it is expected, or you're trying to interface a 32 bit app with a 64 bit dll, or vice versa...